# JavaFx build.fxbuild not working

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, ant, build

I have a JavaFX Application I am trying to deploy. When I fill in the information in the build.fxbuild file, and click 'generate ant build.xml', nothing happens. If i create a new JavaFX application, the ant build works for that. I cannot find any error messages associated with creating the build so I do not know where to start. If anyone has insight into this help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance. I am using JavaFX 8 with Eclipse Neon.

Comment: Can you show the `build.fxbuild` file?

Comment: goto your not working build and check with the working build and see whats up